# How to set navigateurl for radwindow in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, radwindow

How to set navigateurl for radwindow in `javascript` ?

I want to use a radwindow in my page, and I use it in tow part.

I have a radwindow that I use it in 2 part.

```
 <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" ShowContentDuringLoad="false"
              VisibleStatusbar="false"  
         RegisterWithScriptManager="True" 
        EnableShadow="True" ReloadOnShow="true" Width="800px" Height="550px" 
      runat="server">
      <Windows>
            <telerik:RadWindow ID="modalPopup" runat="server" Modal="True"
      >
      </telerik:RadWindow>
 </Windows></telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

I use `javascript` for show radwindow.

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock runat="server" ID="rdbScripts">
      <script type="text/javascript">

          function showDialogInitially() {
              var wnd = $find("<%=modalPopup.ClientID %>");
              wnd.show();
              Sys.Application.remove_load(showDialogInitially);
          }
```

When I click on a button , set `Navigateurl` of `radwindow = ("DefCall.aspx")`  and when I click to other button , set `navigateurl = ("DefTask.aspx")` and passe 2 value to the child page by `QueryString` or other way.

```
protected void btnDefCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string strURL = string.Format("../PhoneCall/DefPhoneCall.aspx
    ?FormTypeID={0}&FormID={1}", number1,number2);
  modalPopup.NavigateUrl = strURL;

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "PopupScript", string.Format("javascript:showDialogInitially()"), true);

}


 protected void btnDefTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strURL = string.Format("../Task/DefTask.aspx?FormTypeID={0}&FormID={1}", (int)clsHelper.FormType.Lead, int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString()));
 modalPopup.NavigateUrl = strURL;

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "PopupScript", string.Format("javascript:showDialogInitially()"), true);
}
```

Comment: Did you try visiting [Telerik Site](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/internalcontent/defaultcs.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [RadWindow API](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-radwindow-methods.html) you can change the url through javascript like this

```
var wnd = $find("<%=modalPopup.ClientID %>");
wnd.setUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **window.radopen**. The only trick is you need to use **pageLoad** which is to wait until the **RadWindow** is fully loaded.

```
protected void btnDefTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var script = string.Concat(
        "function pageLoad() { showDialogInitially('",
        "http://www.telerik.com",
        "'); }");

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), 
       "PopupScript", script, true);
}

<telerik:RadWindowManager 
    ID="RadWindowManager1" 
    ShowContentDuringLoad="false"
    VisibleStatusbar="false"  
    RegisterWithScriptManager="True" 
    EnableShadow="True" 
    ReloadOnShow="true" 
    Width="800px" Height="550px" 
    runat="server">
      <Windows>
        <telerik:RadWindow ID="modalPopup" runat="server" Modal="True">
        </telerik:RadWindow>
    </Windows>
</telerik:RadWindowManager>    
<telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="RadScriptBlock1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showDialogInitially(url) {
            window.radopen(url, "modalPopup");
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</telerik:RadScriptBlock>
```

Comment: I use this code, script type="text/javascript">
              var strURL = "";


              function OpenWindow(url) {
                  strURL = url;
                  Sys.Application.add_load(ow);
              }

              function ow() {
                  var oWnd = radopen(strURL, 'modalPopu');
                  Sys.Application.remove_load(ow);
              }

Comment: But when I close modalwindow and refresh MyPage , modalwindow open again

Comment: It is because browser calls **btnDefTask_Click** again. It is browser's default behavior, and there is nothing you can do about it. One way to prevent it is to use **Javascript** at **client side** to open RadWindows instead of server side button click with **ScriptManager**.

Comment: What do I do to fix this problem, that when the page reloads again , the last button or command , not call?

Comment: When I call a button for delete or save , and reload page again, call the last button or command again :(